# Replace values in masked numpy array not working

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I have the foll. masked array in numpy called arr with shape (50, 360, 720):

```
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 ..., 
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 ..., 
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

It has the foll. data in arr[0]:

```
arr[0].data

array([[-999., -999., -999., ..., -999., -999., -999.],
       [-999., -999., -999., ..., -999., -999., -999.],
       [-999., -999., -999., ..., -999., -999., -999.],
       ..., 
       [-999., -999., -999., ..., -999., -999., -999.],
       [-999., -999., -999., ..., -999., -999., -999.],
       [-999., -999., -999., ..., -999., -999., -999.]])
```

-999. is the missing_value and I want to replace it by 0.0. I do this:

```
arr[arr == -999.] = 0.0
```

However, arr remains the same even after this operation. How to fix this?

Comment: You may have changed the `data` for the array, but you didn't change the mask.

Comment: thanks @hpaulj, how do I fix it?

Comment: I had tried using ma.set_fill_value but that did not seem to work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want `filled`.  I'll illustrate:

```
In [702]: x=np.arange(10)    
In [703]: xm=np.ma.masked_greater(x,5)

In [704]: xm
Out[704]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3 4 5 -- -- -- --],
             mask = [False False False False False False  True  True  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [705]: xm.filled(10)
Out[705]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 10, 10, 10, 10])
```

In this case `filled` replaces all masked values with a fill value.  Without an argument it would use the `fill_value`.

`np.ma` uses this approach to perform many of its calculations.  For example its `sum` is the same as if I filled all masked values with 0.  `prod` would replace them with 1.

```
In [707]: xm.sum()
Out[707]: 15
In [709]: xm.filled(0).sum()
Out[709]: 15
```

The result of `filled` is a regular array, since all masked values have been replaced with something 'normal'.